# spark sql : How to achieve parallel processing of dataframe at group level but with in each group, we require sequential processing of rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parallel-processing, sequential

1. Apply grouping on the data frame. Let us say it resulted in 100 groups with 10 rows each.
2. I have a function that has to be applied on each group. It can happen in parallel fashion and in any order (i.e., it is upto the spark discretion to choose any group in any order for execution).
3. But with in group, I need the guarantee of sequential processing of the rows. Because after processing each row in a group, I use the output in the processing of any of the rows remaining in the group.

We took the below approach where everything was running on the driver and could not utilize the spark cluster's parallel processing across nodes (as expected, performance was real bad)

1) Break the main DF into multiple dataframes, placed in an array :

```
val securityIds = allocStage1DF.select("ALLOCONEGROUP").distinct.collect.flatMap(_.toSeq)
val bySecurityArray = securityIds.map(securityIds => allocStage1DF.where($"ALLOCONEGROUP" <=> securityIds))
```

2) Loop thru the dataframe and pass to a method  to process, row-by-row from above dataframe:

```
df.coalesce(1).sort($"PRIORITY" asc).collect().foreach({
  row => AllocOneOutput.allocOneOutput(row)}
)
```

What we are looking for is a combination of parallel and sequential processing.

1. Parallel processing at group level. because, these are all independent groups and can be parallelized.
2. With in each group, rows have to be processed one after the other in a sequence which is very important for our use case.

[sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Kxy.png)

Apply grouping on SECURITY_ID,CC,BU,MPU which gives us 2 groups from above (SECID_1,CC_A,BU_A,MPU_A and SECID_2,CC_A,BU_A,MPU_A).

with the help of a priority matrix ( nothing but a ref table for assinging rank to rows), we transpose each group into below :

[Transposed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrUth.png)

Each row in the above group has a priority and are sorted in that order. Now, I want to process each row one after the other by passing them to a function and get an output like below :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRMTS.png)

Detailed Explanation of usecase :

1. Base data frame has all trading positions data of a financial firm. some customers buy (long) a given financial product (uniquely identified by securityId) and some sell(short) them.
2. The idea of our application is to identify/pair the long positions and short positions in a given securityId.
3. Since this pairing happens with in a securityId, we said that the base data frame is divided into groups based on this securityId and each group can processed independently.
4. Why are we looking for sequential processing within a group ?  It is because, when there are many long positions and many short positions in a given group (as the example data had) then the reference table (priority matrix) decides which long position has to be paired against which short position. basically, it gives the order of processing.
5. Second reason is that, when a given long quantity and short quantity
   are not equal then the residual quantity is eligible for pairing.
   i.e., if long quantity is left, then it can be paired with the next
   short quantity available in the group as per the priority or vice
   versa.
6. Because of the reasons, mentioned in 4 & 5, we are looking to process row after row with in a group.

Above points are described using the dataset below.

Base DataFrame

```
    +-------------+----------+----------+------
ROW_NO|SECURITY_ID| ACCOUNT|POSITION|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  1|      secId|   Acc1|       +100|
  2|      secId|   Acc2|       -150|
  3|      secId|   Acc3|       -25|
  4|      secId2|   Acc3|       -25|
  5|      secId2|   Acc3|       -25|
```

Base data frame is divided based on group by securityID. Let us use secId group as below

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------
ROW_NO|SECURITY_ID| ACCOUNT|POSITION|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  1|      secId|   Acc1|       +100|
  2|      secId|   Acc2|       -150|
  3|      secId|   Acc3|       -25|
```

In the above case positive position of 100 can be paired with either -50 or -25. In order to break the tie, the following ref table called priority matrix helps by defining the order.

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------
+vePositionAccount|-vePositionAccount| RANK
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  Acc1|            Acc3|              1|     
  Acc1|            Acc2|              2|
```

so, from above matrix we know that rowNo 1 and 3 will be paired first and then rowNo 1 and 2. This is the order (sequential processing) that we are talking about. Lets pair them now as below :

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------
+veROW_NO|+veSECURITY_ID| +veACCOUNT|+vePOSITION|+veROW_NO|+veSECURITY_ID| +veACCOUNT|+vePOSITION|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------
  1|      secId|    Acc1|       +100|      3|       secId|   Acc3|       -25|
  1|      secId|    Acc1|       +100|      2|       secId|   Acc2|       -150|
```

What happens when row 1 is processed after row 2 ? (this is what we need)

1.After processing row 1 - Position in Acc1 will be (100 - 25) = 75 Position in Acc3 will be 0. The updated position in Acc1 which is 75 will be now used in processing second row.

2.After processing row 2 - Position in Acc1 will be 0 . Position in Acc2 will be (75-150) -75.

Result dataframe:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------
ROW_NO|SECURITY_ID| ACCOUNT|POSITION|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  1|      secId|   Acc1|       0|
  2|      secId|   Acc2|       -75|
  3|      secId|   Acc3|       0|
```

What happens when row 2 is processed after row 1 ? (we dont want this)

1. After processing row 2 - Position in Acc1 will be 0 Position in Acc2 will be (100-150) -50. The updated position in Acc1 which is 0 will be now used in processing frist row.
2. After processing row 1 - Position in Acc1 will be 0. Position in Acc3 will be unchanged at -25.

Result dataframe:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------
ROW_NO|SECURITY_ID| ACCOUNT|POSITION|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  1|      secId|   Acc1|       0|
  2|      secId|   Acc2|       -50|
  3|      secId|   Acc3|       -25|
```

As you see above, the order of processing with in a group determines our output

I also wanted to ask - why does not spark support sequential processing with in a section of dataframe ? we are saying that we need parallel processing capability of the cluster. That is why we are dividing the data frame into groups and asking the cluster to apply the logic on these groups in parallel. All we are saying is if the group has lets say 100 rows, then let these 100 rows are processed 1 after other in an order. Is this not supported by spark ?

If it is not, then what other technology in big data can help acheive that ?

**Alternate Implementation:**

1. Partition the dataframe into as many partitions as number of groups (50000 in our case. Groups are more but rows with in any group are no more than few 100s).
2. Run 'ForeachPartition' action on the data frame where in the logic is executed across partitions independently.
3. write the output from processing of each partition to the cluster.
4. After the whole data frame is processed, a seperate job is going to read these individual files from the step 3 and write to a single file/dataframe.

I doubt if thousands of partitions is any good, but yet would like to know if the approach is sounding good.

Comment: collect does not seem a good approach, pls post example in- and output.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Please find example data pasted above.

Comment: unfortunately not clear what u really want, group by, transpose

Comment: sequential processjng is not a Spark thing

Comment: u can zipwithindex and use sparksql to approximate but i find example unclear

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I further explained the usecase and gave the sample data  under title "Detailed Explanation of usecase".  Could you please check and let us know your feedback. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Oddly enough I was faced with bull bear spreads and whilst I could solve it in Spark, I opted to do it outside of Spark. Will post later. Not the way to go.

Comment: so what iv the +100 is -100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept works well enough until this rule:

> 5. Second reason is that, when a given long quantity and short quantity are not equal then the residual quantity is eligible for
>      pairing. i.e., if long quantity is left, then it can be paired with
>      the next short quantity available in the group as per the priority or
>      vice versa.

This is because you want iteration, looping with dependencies logic, that is difficult to code with Spark which is more flow-oriented.

> I also worked on a project where everything was stated - do it in Big
>   Data with Spark, scala or pyspark. Being an architect as well as coder,
>   I looked at the algorithm for something similar to your area, but not
>   quite, in which for commodities all the **periods** for a set of data
>   points needed to be classified as bull, bear, or not. Like your
>   algorithm, but still different, I did not know what amount of looping
>   to do up-front. In fact I needed to do something, then decide to
>   repeat that something to the left and to the right of a period I had
>   marked as either bull or bear or nothing, potentially. Termination
>   conditions were required. See picture below. Sort of like a 'flat' binary tree 
>   traversal until all paths exhausted. Not that Spark-ish.

[image]

> I actually - for academic purposes - solved my specific situation in
>   Spark, but it was an academic exercise. The point to the matter is
>   that this type of processing - my example and your example are a poor
>   fit for Spark. We did these **calculation in ORACLE** and simply **sqooped**
>   the results to Hadoop datastore.

My advice is therefore that you not try this in Spark, as it does not fit the use cases well enough. Trust me, it gets messy. To be honest, it was soon apparent to me that this type of processing was an issue. But when starting out, it is a common aspect to query.

Comment: Thanks for the detail above. I am inclined towards your advice. In your case, for generating the combinations, are your relying on a bucket size of say 6 elements and moving the bucket along ? Applying to left and right of the marked period is something that is not very clear to me.

separately, could you please comment on an approach under title 'alternate implementation' if it is worth pursuing ?

Comment: U start with a set of data points. If u get a range that is a bear period, then that will often be a subset of the overall set of data points. What of all the other points to the left and right? assuming somewhere  in the middle. U need to do the processing to the left if the found initial  range and to the right. And so on. So as to classify those other timeframes. That is where Spark does NOZt excel. I wrote a nifty left right traversal.

Comment: Ok on alt approach. How to get a partition per group? Then you r using iterables and low level coding. Not Spark Scala really anymore. Use a proper programming language.

Comment: Too difficult in my view.

Comment: OK, on alt approach I meant. The comma changes context!

Comment: Yeah, we were looking at iterables and low level coding to an extent. For use cases like these, what other alternative APIs apart from spark in Big Data Ecosystem come close please.

Comment: Spark is not an alternative. Java, oracle pl sql, .net. Easier, tools suchas Informatica, Talend et al not the go. in my opinion. i did tgat example in pl sql.

Comment: Just as aside, when I solved this it was in the USA subsidiary how did he do that?

Comment: Thank You for the detailed help. This conversation helps us to take further steps in right direction.

Comment: Does UDAFs help solve this use case in Spark ? Running a UDAF function per group and with in the UDAF function - attempt to process row after row.
We are doing a theoretical analysis at this point. If you have any pointers, that will be of great help.

Comment: Did not see any upvote. Interesting point but there are all these concerns on UDFs and UDAFs. Will ponder later.

Comment: Sure, please let us know.
Between I already upvoted and it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: Had forgotten that. Some strange rules.

Comment: Hi. Should we choose to not use spark for our use case and take an alternate approach to solve the problem using other technology (say regular java or pl/sql) - The underlying problem scope to process group of records in parallel remain the same. For example, in our use case there are 100 million records to be processed  in total. If we divide them into groups, we are left with around 60000 groups. I need the help from programming API to be able to process these 60000 groups in parallel as much as possible since this is a intraday requirement. Any thoughts on this pls ?

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to get the desired throughput without using a cluster but I dont see one. No matter the technology I chose, I need to utilize the computing resources from several machines in parallel. If spark does not deliver this for my use case, how can any other technology do ? Apologies if it does not sound right, I am trying to understand how the traditional apis such as  pl/sql or java score over spark ?

Comment: Need to think on this

Comment: You will need to schedule a number of same programs processing ranges of data in parallel in partitions with indexing. Or create N non partititioned tables of 10M records that you process in parallel, with indexes. That is how it was done in the past.

Comment: You can do part on Spark and latter on other platform.

Comment: Understood your point. Can you clarify your last comment pls. what part on spark did you refer to ?

Comment: Grouping into groups and writing out to different tables as stated, ten times from DF. // Saving data to a JDBC source
jdbcDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .save()

Comment: Except you filter the data 10 times (with caching ) and save to 10 tables.

Comment: I think I might have earnt an upvote - what do you think?